# RoslynCodeAnalysisService exception when coding

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

While using VisualStudio 2019 with my own source generator. I'm having an exception inside visual studio and it prompts me to open a debugger.

This only happens while coding and not while building (which make me thinks that my source generators is fine).

When trying to debug I see a blank page and call stack does not have any informations.

I know it must be linked to my generator but I don't know how. Any tips on how to debug would be greatly appreciated.

Full source code is available here : https://github.com/kYann/StrongTypeId/tree/master/src/StrongType.Generators

```cs
[Generator]
    public class StrongTypeIdGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        Template template;

        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            var file = "StrongTypeId.sbntxt";
            template = Template.Parse(EmbeddedResource.GetContent(file), file);

            context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new StrongTypeIdReceiver());
        }

        private string GenerateStrongTypeId(string @namespace, string className)
        {
            var model = new
            {
                Namespace = @namespace,
                ClassName = className,
            };

            // apply the template
            var output = template.Render(model, member => member.Name);

            return output;
        }

        public bool IsStrongTypeId(INamedTypeSymbol recordSymbol)
        {
            var strongTypeIdType = typeof(StrongTypeId<>);
            var originalBaseTypeDef = recordSymbol.BaseType.OriginalDefinition;
            var baseTypeAssembly = originalBaseTypeDef.ContainingAssembly;

            var isSameAssembly = baseTypeAssembly.ToDisplayString() == strongTypeIdType.Assembly.FullName;
            var isSameTypeName = strongTypeIdType.Name == originalBaseTypeDef.MetadataName;

            return isSameAssembly && isSameTypeName;
        }

        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            if (context.SyntaxReceiver is not StrongTypeIdReceiver receiver)
                return;

            foreach (var rds in receiver.RecordDeclarations)
            {
                var model = context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(rds.SyntaxTree);

                if (model.GetDeclaredSymbol(rds) is not INamedTypeSymbol recordSymbol)
                    continue;

                if (!IsStrongTypeId(recordSymbol))
                    continue;

                var ns = recordSymbol.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString();
                var output = GenerateStrongTypeId(ns, recordSymbol.Name);

                // add the file
                context.AddSource($"{recordSymbol.Name}.generated.cs", SourceText.From(output, Encoding.UTF8));
            }
        }

        private class StrongTypeIdReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
        {
            public StrongTypeIdReceiver()
            {
                RecordDeclarations = new();
            }

            public List<RecordDeclarationSyntax> RecordDeclarations { get; private set; }

            public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
            {
                if (syntaxNode is RecordDeclarationSyntax rds &&
                    rds.BaseList is not null)
                {
                    this.RecordDeclarations.Add(rds);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

RoslynCodeAnalysisService has an aggresive caching strategy and was holding previous source generator in memory.
Restarting visual studio did the tricks